# How to Print Global Ktable in scala for kafka?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ktable

I am trying to see how GlobalKtable works in kafka and for that i am trying to write sample code.
I have created globalKtable but i want to see that too
I have tried peek function but its not available, now i am trying by view but its giving compile time error.

what is the write way to see globalktable in scala?

what i have tried is

```
'''
 val genderGlobalTable: GlobalKTable[String, abc] = builder
        .globalTable(kafkaStreamConfig.getString("abc-topic"),
          Materialized.as("abcStore")
            .withKeySerde(stringSerde)
            .withValueSerde(abcSerde))
    
      implicit val streams: KafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), properties)
    
      val view: ReadOnlyKeyValueStore[String, abc] = streams
        .store("abcStore", new QueryableStoreType[abc])

'''
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an instance of `QueryableStoreType` that is an interface. Instead, you need to use the factory class `QueryableStoreTypes` (note, that the name is plural while the interface name is singular) to get the type you need.

For a `GlobalKTable` you can use `QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore()` (or depending on your Kafka Streams version, `QueryableStoreTypes.timestampedKeyValueStore()`).